# how to automatically handle errors emails (unknown recipient) via postfix / linux server

Tags: php, postfix-mta, email-bounces

I need to automatically manage emails not delivered by postfix if the email address is invalid.
I use phpmailer to send emails, postfix runs on my debian server, and I would like to be able to store invalid emails to clean my different databases.

I do not quite see how to approach the thing, emailing tools type Eloqua, Mailchimp etc handle hardbounceback, but concretely how?
The only way I have found and that looks the most reliable is the addition of Reply-To:
Return-Path: in the header of the email to receive an email from the SMTP server when the email is unknown? You confirm me?
But if that is the case ? We must send the email to a php script as in the example ?
[How to handle bounce email with postfix and php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55619256/how-to-handle-bounce-email-with-postfix-and-php)

But if so, the return emails are never the same, what to search and parse in these emails that could correspond to an error, the headers have no standard return ?
If anyone has an idea or a track, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an email bounce even when an email adres is valid. Think of "mailbox full" messages. I found this link with which you can contact the SMTP server and ask it if the email adress exsist:

https://www.codexworld.com/verify-email-address-check-if-real-exists-domain-php/

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not find this class php, but the tests that I made sent me several "false positives", it seems that it works well for private email addresses (gmail etc), or smtp without anti spam for example, but I have done several tests on addresses of companies, which have antispams or more advanced configurations, and the script tells me that the address exists, even if I try with fake accounts (ex: xezrrdfjd @ ....), I only get 250 answers and no return in 550 :/

if I send via my mailbox on these fake email, I receive an email return address unknown

Comment: @Mikael I guess you're right. Well, then an other thing to try is [parsing the postfix logs](https://github.com/jors/postfixlogparser).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the information given by the logs is not reliable either. Postfix or syslog  do not tell me that emails are bounces for the tests I have done on emails from "real" companies that have antispam and good configurations of their SMTP servers: / The only solution the most "reliable" I see is to retrieve and process the response emails if the recipient is unknown, but I do not see patterns in the headers of emails that could help me easily and automatically process these emails :/

Comment: Well, at least you have now researched all possible alternatives. The only other way seems to be to inspect all bounces and analyse their content.